# EF6 Raw SqlQuery do not read value data

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

i am new in EF.
Reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx) it's possible to use SQL queries for non-entity types.

I have this class:

```
Public Class MyNoEntityClass
    Public ID As Integer
    Public Field1 As Decimal
    Public Field2 As Decimal
End Class
```

I try to load data from database using dbcontext:

```
Dim aRecords As List(Of MyNoEntityClass) = db.Database
         .SqlQuery(Of MyNoEntityClass)("SELECT ID, Field1, Field2 FROM MyTable")
         .ToList
```

After i check the number of element with

```
console.writeline(aRecords.Count)
```

and the value is correct, list contains same records number. Then i do

```
For Each oData As MyNoEntityClass In aRecords 
    Console.WriteLine(oData.ID)
    Console.WriteLine(oData.Field1)
    Console.WriteLine(oData.Field2)
Next
```

and all values are zero.

Why ? Where is my wrong ?
Database columns are same type of MyNoEntityClass (ID integer, Field1 and Field2 decimal).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF does not bind values to public fields. Make them properties

```
Public Class MyNoEntityClass
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Field1 As Decimal
    Public Property Field2 As Decimal
End Class
```